# Compiler crashes on generic lambda

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, c++14

I have C++14 enabled in code (a Qt5 project) similar to the following:

```
auto func = [&](auto p, auto pp) {
    if(!p)
        return;
    pp = p;
    p->init();
    this->member_function(pp->thing()); // replaces member_function(pp->thing());
};
MyClass *p1;
...
func(p1, m_p);
m_p->doSomething();
```

After receiving:

```
internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
```

Debugging I found `m_p`did not change after the call to `func`, as I was expecting. Does generic lambda (`auto`) really works so? How do I go to change `m_p` in code like the above?

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing the title and the issue with the language feature. Does "Generic Template" go by another name? Or is this a problem with Auto-typed variables, Return type deduction or Lambdas? Also see [C++ Standards Support in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html).

Comment: Sometimes compilation errors trigger compiler errors. Maybe other parts of your code (e.g. doSomething()) generate a compilation error and that in turn exposes a bug in the compiler. Try other compilers or figure out what is wrong in your code (without the help of the compiler). To begin with remove the caputure `&` in the lambda as it is not necessary.

Comment: Show the declaration of `m_p`.

Comment: @Oktalist `m_p` is a class member pointer to a plugin which is being loaded.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not gcc's bugzilla. Upvoters: you should know better.

Comment: @alfC capture `&` was required because a class member function is called, `this->member_function(pp->thing());`. And I found there is gcc bug related to this, not using `this->` exposes it (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61636).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Segmentation fault in the compiler is very bad, but have you tried using `auto& pp`? It looks like `m_p` is being passed by value, not reference.

Answer (score 8):

File a bug report in gcc's bugzilla. Whether your code is valid C++, or not, the compiler should not blow up with a segmentation fault.

Comment: May I ask you to be a little more verbose?

Comment: You are perfectly free to ask me to be more verbose. But there's nothing else to say: congratulations, you found a bug in gcc. For your prize, you get a completely free bug report in gcc's bugzilla!

Comment: What makes you think the OP is using GCC?

Comment: Elementary. You don't get 'segmentation fault's on Windowsware. By process of elimination, there aren't that many possibilities left.

Comment: Well, it works with clang. Actually, I'm on Debian Jessie trying both gcc and clang after received `internal compiler error: Segmentation fault` on Windows MinGW.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik, bug (already) found, generic lambda "cannot call member function without object" - https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61636.